# Oracle Join Table from SubQuery

Tags: oracle, join, subquery, max, distinct

I am trying to join A subquery to another table. 
How can I achieve this?

Below is what I am trying to achieve.
I have a table 1 and table 2 - which I have successfully joined.
The results are shown below

```
select max(popi.po_po_id) as PO_ID, 
rps.rp_rp_id_artl as STYLE
from table1 popi
inner join table2 rps
on rps.rp_rp_id_artl = popi.popi_for
where popi.popi_for = '100466'
group by rps.rp_rp_id_artl
```

Result is:

```
PO_ID |STYLE |
--------------
1004  |100466|
```

I now need to link the results from the above so I can link table 3 and bring back the sup_id from table3:

```
table3:
PO_ID |SUP_ID
-----------------
1001  |Sup1
1002  |Sup2
1003  |Sup3
1004  |Sup4
```

In the end I am after the following result:

```
PO_ID |STYLE |SUP_ID
-----------------
1004  |100466|Sup4
```

Any help on joining the tables together would be great.

I am trying to achieve this by doing a subquery and then joining the results to the main table.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use your first query as an inline view, and join it with the second table, like so:

```
select PO_ID, STYLE, table3.sup_id
from (
  select max(popi.po_po_id) as PO_ID, 
  rps.rp_rp_id_artl as STYLE
  from table1 popi
  inner join table2 rps
  on rps.rp_rp_id_artl = popi.popi_for
  where popi.popi_for = '100466'
  group by rps.rp_rp_id_artl
) max_po_by_style
inner join table3
on table3.po_id = max_po_by_style.po_id
```

The same effect can also be achieved, perhaps more clearly, with a factored subquery:

```
with max_po_by_style as (
  select max(popi.po_po_id) as PO_ID, 
  rps.rp_rp_id_artl as STYLE
  from table1 popi
  inner join table2 rps
  on rps.rp_rp_id_artl = popi.popi_for
  where popi.popi_for = '100466'
  group by rps.rp_rp_id_artl
select PO_ID, STYLE, table3.sup_id
from max_po_by_style
inner join table3
on table3.po_id = max_po_by_style.po_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(popi.po_po_id) as PO_ID, 
rps.rp_rp_id_artl as STYLE, t3.sup_id
from table1 popi
inner join table2 rps
on rps.rp_rp_id_artl = popi.popi_for
inner join table3 t3
on popi.po_po_id = t3.po_id
where popi.popi_for = '100466'
group by rps.rp_rp_id_artl, t3.sup_id
```

You may join multiple tables at once - joins can connect two, three, or more tables

As David Costa commented there can be a problem if `po_po_id` exists in table1, table2 and table3, but is not the max for the `rp_rp_id_artl` in table2. So this query may potentially return more rows then the query which joins table3 with the result of grouping

Comment: I would take the same approach. Why not provide some explanation?

Comment: I suspect this would give incorrect results.  Since the value of SUP_ID depends on the value of PO_PO_ID, joining prior to grouping, and including SUP_ID in the grouping, definitely has the potential to change the results and in this case I believe would be incorrect.

Comment: @Dave Costa if there is a one to many relationship between table1 and table3 then you are right (the joins kind of hint at this, yet the sample data does not reveal this nor do we have info on primary keys or constraints). With the information we have, it is unclear.  Probably the best we can do is honor the OP's question and respond with a subquery or a subquery factoring clause.